# Is "not even ever more" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

> And still, we are compel to a critical approach to our practices if –as Ferrajoli claims- even very realistic reasons –that is, prudential reasons- are invoked: our own lives –***and not even ever more*** the maintenance of our current welfare- might be at stake.

In the piece above, quoted from a paper study, is "and not even ever more" grammatical?

Apart the fact that I have general problems to understand usage of words like "even" and "ever", especially when they are joined with "not", I ask because I found only an instance of "not even ever" on The New York Times ( "That may not even ever happen") , and this circumstance make me suspicious that in that phrase there is something wrong, but I don't understand what.

Comment: Well, "we are compel" is not the sort of mistake a native speaker would ever make, so I'm guessing this paper (1) was not written by a native speaker, and (2) is in sore need of a competent copy editor.

Comment: @Martha, yes, the writer is not an English mother tongue, as it seems reading their name, but what is wrong in "not even ever more"?

Comment: What is wrong with it is that it makes no sense whatsoever. English words, but not an English sentence.

Comment: This is Too Localised. There's nothing useful to be learnt from what looks more like a bad translation than anything else.

Comment: The author appears to be Spanish; if you do not know Spanish yourself you might ask a Spanish speaker to back-translate the phrase and see if it makes sense in that language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question of grammaticality doesn’t arise; *and not even ever more* isn't even approximately English.

I *think* what is meant is what we would express with something like ***and not merely X***, meaning “I will not address the far less important matter of maintaining our current welfare”. But I am not at all confident it is not in fact just the opposite: ***to say nothing of X***, meaning “I will not go so far as to raise  the even more important matter of maintaining our current welfare”.

In any case, however you translate that phrase, it is still a horrible sentence. I decline to believe that three such parentheses are tolerated in contemporary academic prose in any language. This makes Hegel look like Hemingway.

Comment: relevent: http://existentialcomics.com/comic/62

Comment: @thedarkwanderer Love it! *Wovon man nicht sprechen kann, darüber muß man schweigen.*